# Program breaks after inputting anything other than numbers

Tags: c, char

So I made this Memory Game project using C for school. And after trying for quite some time I just can't fix that after putting any symbol instead of a number breaks the whole thing. I have tried using <ctype.h> isdigit() function but it doesn't seem to help. So, is there any way to fix that? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void printInterface(char i0, char i1, char i2, char i3, char i4, char i5, char i6, char i7, int gCount);

int main(){
    srand(time(0));                         // CARD DECLARATION
    int pair1,pair11,pair2,pair22,pair3,pair33,pair4,pair44;
    int choice1, choice12, choice2, choice22, guesses=0;
    char yesNo='G';
    pair1 = rand()%8+1;             //pair1
    for(;;){
        pair11 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair11!=pair1)break;
    }
    
    for(;;){                        //pair2
        pair2 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair2!=pair1 && pair2!=pair11)break;
    }
    for(;;){
        pair22 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair22!=pair2 && pair22!=pair1 && pair22!=pair11)break;
    }
    
    for(;;){                        //pair3
        pair3 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair3!=pair1 && pair3!=pair11 && pair3!=pair2 && pair3!=pair22)break;
    }
    for(;;){
        pair33 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair33!=pair1 && pair33!=pair11 && pair33!=pair2 && pair33!=pair22 && pair33!=pair3)break;
    }
    
    for(;;){                        //pair4
        pair4 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair4!=pair1 && pair4!=pair11 && pair4!=pair2 && pair4!=pair22 && pair4!=pair3 && pair4!=pair33)break;
    }
    for(;;){
        pair44 = rand()%8+1;
        if(pair44!=pair1 && pair44!=pair11 && pair44!=pair2 && pair44!=pair22 && pair44!=pair3 && pair44!=pair33 && pair44!=pair4)break;
    }
    
                                    //Declare symbols to cards
    char guess[8];
    char numbers[8] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};
    char numbersOrg[8] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};
    char symbol[4]= {'%', '@', '$', '^'};
    guess[pair1-1] = symbol[0]; guess[pair11-1] = symbol[0]; 
    guess[pair2-1] = symbol[1]; guess[pair22-1] = symbol[1]; 
    guess[pair3-1] = symbol[2]; guess[pair33-1] = symbol[2]; 
    guess[pair4-1] = symbol[3]; guess[pair44-1] = symbol[3]; 
    
    system("mode 23, 20");                                                          // INTERFACE 
    do{
    printInterface(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3],numbers[4],numbers[5],numbers[6],numbers[7],guesses);
    printf("   Choose first card:\n");                                              //FIRST CHOICE
    printf("           ");scanf("%i", &choice1);
    choice12=choice1-1;
    if(choice1<1 || choice1>8){                                                     //FIRST INVALID CHOICE CHECK
            printf("    Invalid choice");Sleep(1000);system("cls");
        }
    else if(numbers[choice12]!=numbersOrg[choice12]){
        printf("    Invalid choice");Sleep(1000);system("cls");
    }   
        else{
                numbers[choice12]=guess[choice12];
                system("cls");
                printInterface(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3],numbers[4],numbers[5],numbers[6],numbers[7],guesses);
                printf("  Choose second card:\n");                                  //SECOND CHOICE
                printf("           ");scanf("%i", &choice2);
                choice22=choice2-1;
                if(choice2<1 || choice2>8 || choice2==choice1){                     //SECOND INVALID CHOICE CHECK
                    printf("    Invalid choice");Sleep(1000);system("cls");
                    numbers[choice12]=numbersOrg[choice12];
                }
                else if(numbers[choice22]!=numbersOrg[choice22]){
                    printf("    Invalid choice");Sleep(1000);system("cls");
                    numbers[choice12]=numbersOrg[choice12];
                }
                else{   
                        numbers[choice22]=guess[choice22];
                        system("cls");
                        printInterface(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3],numbers[4],numbers[5],numbers[6],numbers[7],guesses);
                            if(guess[choice12] == guess[choice22]){
                                printf("      Guessed it!\n");guesses++;            //RIGHT OR WRONG CHECK
                            }else{
                                printf("         Wrong!\n");
                                guesses++;
                                numbers[choice12]=numbersOrg[choice12];
                                numbers[choice22]=numbersOrg[choice22];
                            }
                        printf("     Press Enter...");
                        getchar();getchar();system("cls");
                    }   
                }
                                                                                    //CHECK IF FINSIHED
        if(numbers[0]!=numbersOrg[0] && numbers[1]!=numbersOrg[1] && numbers[2]!=numbersOrg[2] && numbers[3]!=numbersOrg[3] && numbers[4]!=numbersOrg[4] && numbers[5]!=numbersOrg[5] && numbers[6]!=numbersOrg[6] && numbers[7]!=numbersOrg[7]){
            printf("         PEXESO\n");            
            printf("=======================\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            printf("        Victory!\n");
            printf("   Number of guesses:\n");
            printf("           %i\n\n", guesses);
            printf("   Enter to continue\n");getchar();getchar();
            system("cls");
            do{
            printf("         PEXESO\n");            
            printf("=======================\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            printf("       Again?(Y/N)");
            yesNo = getchar();
            system("cls");
            if(yesNo=='Y' || yesNo=='y'){
                printf("         PEXESO\n");            
                printf("=======================\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                printf("     Restarting...");Sleep(1500);
                system("cls");
                main();
            }
            if(yesNo=='N' || yesNo=='n'){
                printf("         PEXESO\n");            
                printf("=======================\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                goto out;
                
            }
            }while(yesNo!='Y' || yesNo!='y' || yesNo!='N' || yesNo!='n');   
    }
    }while(true);
    out:
    printf("        Closing...");Sleep(1500);
}

void printInterface(char i0, char i1, char i2, char i3, char i4, char i5, char i6, char i7, int gCount){
    printf("         PEXESO      %.2i\n", gCount);          
    printf("=======================\n\n");
    printf(" ***   ***   ***   ***\n");
    printf(" *%c*   *%c*   *%c*   *%c*\n", i0,i1,i2,i3);
    printf(" ***   ***   ***   ***\n\n");
    
    printf(" ***   ***   ***   ***\n");
    printf(" *%c*   *%c*   *%c*   *%c*\n", i4,i5,i6,i7);
    printf(" ***   ***   ***   ***\n");
}
```

Comment: `choice1` is not initialized.  If `scanf("%i", &choice1);` does not read any data from the stream (eg, if the data cannot be interpreted as an integer), then `choice1` is not assigned a value.  A subsequent attempt to access `choice1` is undefined behavior. You *must* *alway* *check* the return value of `scanf`.  Always.

Comment: Any input value which can't be processed by `scanf` remains in the input buffer. You have to clear it somehow. It will be easier if you stop using `scanf` and get every input into a string with `fgets`. Then extract data from the string with `sscanf`. ***Always*** check the return value from `scanf` function family (the number of successful conversions). If it's incorrect, just dump the string and input another. Aside: don't use `%i` use `%d` anyway unless you allow octal input.

Comment: Oh and don't call `main()` from `main()`. It's a terrible way to go.

Comment: OT: the function `getchar()` returns an INT, not a CHAR